# How to get report based on total order value and postal group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hi I am trying to generate a report total customers, total orders , revenue and average order value where orders are under £15 and delivery method by standard in one table and £15-£20 orders and standard in other table. 
Bellow is my query.

```
    [Customer no]
    [Order No],
    [Amount],
    [Shipping Service]
    [Shipping Amount]
    FROM [Better$Internet Order] io
    INNER JOIN [Better$Consignment] IC
    ON IC.[Order No]=OH.[Order No]
    WHERE   [order date] >= '2016-08-01' AND 
    [order date] <= '2016-08-31' AND [COUNTRY]='UNITED KINGDOM' and oh.
    [type] like 'order%' and  [Shipping Service]='Standard'
    Group by 
    [Customer no]
    [Order No],
    [Amount],
    [Shipping Service]
    [Shipping Amount]
    ORDER BY [AMOUNT] ASC
```

In my query I have given "customer no" to get total customers and"order no" to get total orders because one customer might order few times in a month. "order dates", "country" and "type" is orders so it only gets orders not refunds or replacements. I would like to get only and "shipping service" is standard. Thank for the help in advance.

```
   **table data:** 
   Customer no| order No| Amount | Shipping Service
   -------------------------------------------------
          1   |    254  |   8    |     standard
          2   |    258  |   12   |     Tracked
          1   |    260  |   10   |     Standard
          3   |    285  |   13   |     Tracked
          4   |    295  |   11   |     Standard


  Expected results: 
  Month         Aug 2016      

  Under 15 | Standard Delivery | Total customer  - 2   
                                 Total orders    - 3 
                                 total revenue   -  £18
                                 AOV             - £9
             Tracked Delivery  | Total customer  - 2   
                                 Total orders    - 2 
                                 total revenue   - 25
                                 AOV             - 12.50
```

Comment: Seems like you've lost the first part of the query. Copy and paste issue?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: Hi , I am just learning sql, I do not have first part.

Comment: @jarlh have updated question with table data and expected results

Comment: Seems like a `GROUP BY` will be needed, with `case` expressions for the price classes.

Comment: @jarlh do you mean like this :::::    case when [amount] <= '15.00' then 'Under 15' 
      when[amount] between'15.00' and '17.50'then 'Under 17.50'
      when [amount] <='20.00' then 'Under 20'
      else 'Above 20' end as [Amount],
   count(1) as Count

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: @jarlh for count it's not counting how many all rows coming as 1 at end i was expecting total of that case!!!

Comment: To get better assistance, simplify your problem. Add sample table data and the expected result as (formatted) text - not as images.

Comment: @jarlh I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the inside, in a derived table, have a `case` expression to determine price class. `GROUP BY` that result to calculate for each price class/shipping type:

```
select amountclass, "Shipping Service",
       count(distinct "Customer no") as "Total customers",
       count(*) as "Total orders",
       sum("Amount") as "total revenue",
       avg("Amount" * 1.0) as "AOV"
from
(
    select "Customer no", "order No", "Amount", "Shipping Service"
           case when "Amount" < 15 then "Under 15"
                else "Over 15"
           end as amountclass
    from tablename
) dt
group by amountclass, "Shipping Service"
order by amountclass, "Shipping Service"
```

Using double quotes (e.g. `"Shipping Service"` for delimited identifiers is ANSI SQL. (Some dbms products also have square brackets as alternative.)